# Revert Hashmap to previous value

Tags: java

I have a class called Varfoo that stores variables. I have another class called Replacement that uses a hashmap to replace the x into 2. With the forget method, it's meant to forget replacing x with 2.

```
    Varfoo x = new VarFoo("x");
    Replacement s = new Replacement();
    s.put(new VarFoo("x"), new IntFoo(2));
    x.applyReplacement(s);
    s.forget(x);
```

Here's the forget method:

```
public boolean forget(VarFoo var) {
    if (var == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else {
        if (replacementMap.containsKey(var)) {
            replacementMap.remove(var);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It will result to null because I've removed the key itself, not what I intended. How do I revert it back to how it was?

Equals and hashcodes of Varfoo:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (!(o instanceof VarFoo))
        return false;
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    return name.equals(((VarFoo) o).name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more, that's unclear ? Did you implement hashcode and equals in your Varfoo class ?

Comment: You'll need to keep a history of previous values.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13922809/1707353)?

Comment: @azro Added them.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new implementation of `Map`, that contains two (e.g.) `HashMaps`. In normal mode it forwards every operation to `map1`.  This is the original map. `map2` is `null`.

When you make a savepoint, you assign an empty map to `map2`. `get` operations now go first to `map2` and then, if not found, to `map1`. `put` operations go only to `map2`. When you call `forget`, you assign again `null` to `map2`.

Of course, you must implement all the other methods of the `Map` interface. But this should be a simple task. Take care of removes, if needed (maybe you will need a `Set` of removed keys.

Hint: You can use `java.util.AbstractMap` as a base for your implementation.

Comment: This answer can be extended to use a stack of maps, allowing arbitrarily many "save points" to be set and later reverted to. The time complexity of operations like `get` and `containsKey` operations will depend on the number of "save points" currently active.

Comment: Is there any written example of this? Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @reiko1879: Sorry, I do not know an example. I did not search for a generally available implementation of my idea.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward. You create a class, implement `Map` and all its methods by just forwarding the call to the current actual internal map. Those internal maps you can maintain as field, for example stored in a `List<Map<...>>`. And then you add those extra methods to manage them.